# accordion content not showing - JQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am trying to toggle content, accordion style by clicking on a header. Here is my example, When I run through Firebug the .click function gets called but the accordion content does not toggle. I tried several different selector combinations yet no success.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

```
 <style type="text/css">

.content { display: none;}

</style>
<div class="accordion complete" id="step_1">
  <div class="accordion-tab">Step 1.</div>
    <span>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque blandit aliquam malesuada. 

        </p>
    </div>
   </span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".accordion-tab").click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('span').find('.content').not(':animated').slideToggle();


        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) not [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> closest -> Description: For each element in the set, get the first
> element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and
> traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.
>
> closest matches current element or the ancestors in the DOM.

> next ->Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each
> element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it
> retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qRpqc/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".accordion-tab").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('span').find('.content').not(':animated').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get out this "closest('span') as it's searching on the ancestors, not on the children:
[JQuery#closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

so your query need to be:

```
$(this).find('.content').not(':animated').slideToggle();
```

And as a hint, always test in your favorite browser's console the jquery's selection sequence, it's very easy to get lost on it.